# Calculate how big a variable is in relation to others

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, quantiles, ranking

This will sound weird, but I'm trying to calculate something that I don't know the name.

I want to calculate how big/low a variable is in relation to the others. Like Google webmaster tools says "your site loads in 3s, this is slower than 59% of sites". How can I calculate this?

For example, the points a player has. He has 4440 points and he is ranked on #437 out of 16801 players. The average of points in 976 and the top player has 30076 points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make various statements about relations, such as

- Your player has $\frac{4440}{976} \approx 4.5$ times the average number of points.
- He has $\frac{4440}{30076} \approx 15\%$ of the highest score.
- His points total is lower than that of $\frac{436}{16801} \approx 2.6\%$ of players.

Answer (score 1):

Statements about being better (or worse) than some percentage of others is refered to as percentiles (or quantiles if not limited to percents).  These can be calculated by direct comparison to a large number of measured subjects, or based on a theoretical distribution (if you are 2 standard deviation above the mean and the population is approximately normal then you are at about the 95th percentile).